# How to create a java class for method overloading in the given main method

Tags: java

```
class Area
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ....
        ....
        AreaPrinter.getArea().print(x);
        AreaPrinter.getArea().print(x,y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Well ... entering code there seems like a good way to start ....

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna have an example of how a method overloading look like i will give you an example.

```
class DisplayOverloading
{
    public void disp(char c)
    {
         System.out.println(c);
    }
    public void disp(char c, int num)  
    {
         System.out.println(c + " "+num);
    }
}
class Sample
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       DisplayOverloading obj = new DisplayOverloading();
       obj.disp('a');
       obj.disp('a',10);
   }
}
```

Output :

```
a
a 10
```

if you wanna know more about overloading methods, look this page:
http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Basically, overloading refers to defining a family of functions with same name, but different number and types of arguments.

For example, a simple function `sum` can be overloaded to accept 2 or `n` number of arguments. One thing to note that since `main` method is `static` and `static` methods can only access static, function overloading can be performed in the same class as `main` by declaring the `sum` function to be `static` as well

```
public class SumTest {
    public static int sum(int n1, int n2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public static int sum(int[] ar) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int n: ar)
            s += n;
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println("Sum of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5: " + sum(ar));
        System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 2: " + sum(1, 2));
    }
}
```